# Text over images that scrolls horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am editing a code i found that uses overflow to arrange images so that they are scrollable horizontally. Primarily planning to use this on a webpage when the screen width gets smaller (mobile etc). Thats latter is a function that i can set for this specific code on the webpage, so no need to code that in.

But. What i am struggling to figure out is how to put text over (not on top) the images. In other words, where baby Yodas face is (edited in after question about clarification). Specifically text over the individual images that stays within the image borders.

I am not that familiar with html / css, so if someone knows the answer it would be appreciated it they could add an example. (edited in after question about clarification)

I don't have any text elements in the code, because I think I was quite far away from the solution with mye efforts. So I left it out in order to clean up the code a bit.

My example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dca8gp9n/)
Updated with a "working" example. But I am not quite sure why it works, and maybe (quite certain of it) there are som unnecessary coding in it.

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 360px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='scrolling-wrapper'>
  <div class='card'>
    <a href='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'> <img height=3 50px; src='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <a href='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'> <img height=3 50px; src='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <a href='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'> <img height=3 50px; src='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the code is a bit messy I apologize on advance.

Comment: In your demo, where is the text you are trying to place? And to be clear, it should appear above the image, not layered on top, correct?

Comment: Hi. I removed the parts of the code where i had tried adding text to the image since I think I was quite far away from the ansver. I wish to have layered text over the Image. Or in other words it should be where baby Yodas face is. Over / on top, when i think about it I am not totally sure whats the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

You must add a class that must define the position of that text. In this case, I think a "STICKY" text could be good, but you have to add a z-index:1000.

[image: trying some stuff on my localhost]

> top: 0% = top of the element.
>   top: (50% - element.height); example:[top:40%; height:10%;]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>

            .scrolling-wrapper {
              overflow-x: visible;
              overflow-y: hidden;
              /*white-space: nowrap;*/
              height: 360px;
            }
            .card {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 100%;
                width: 33%;
            }           
            .text{
                 position: sticky;
                 top: 25%;
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 0px;
                 margin: 0 auto;
                 text-align: center;
                 z-index: 100;       
            }

            .text p{
                width:60%;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding:1em;
                background-color: white;
            }

            .text:hover{
                background-color: aquamarine;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class='scrolling-wrapper'>
        <div class='card'>
            <a href='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
                <div class="text"><p>Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...</p></div>
                <img height = 350px; src='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class='card'>
            <a href='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
                <div class="text"><p>Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...Your text here...</p></div>
                <img height = 350px; src='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class='card'>
            <a href='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
                <div class="text"><p>Your text here...</p></div>
                <img height = 350px; src='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried something similar @Santiago Cabrera. However I used the div element insted of span, but with visually the same result. The text places at the side (or underneath / on top , depends on how you position the div) instead of placing over the image.

Comment: I Fixed it a bit, @RonnyDeila.

Comment: Ahh, perfect @Santiago Cabrera. Works like a charm :)

Comment: Almost works like a charm. I see that adding text is creating white space above and dragging the images downwards. It gets quite visible when you up-adjust the font-size.. Any ideas on how to solve this? @Santiago Cabrera

Comment: You must define a height for the div that contains the text. .text{height: 0px;} @RonnyDeila. Try again with the code

Comment: Well that put me on to the right track. With some trial and error I got it working the way i desired (visually). For some reason that I cannot understand the pure existence og the div class made it possible to have text where I wanted it, without the text effecting the position or size of the images. I updated the JSFiddle in my question if you wold like to have a look at it. Thank for the help @Santigo Cabrera

Comment: I've checked your example, @RonnyDeila. I think now works how you wanted. You're welcome, great to know that I've helped ;D